# Is there any client-side solution to showing PDFs in an iframe with response type application/octet-stream (rather than downloading)?

Tags: javascript, pdf, iframe

I am fetching some PDFs from an API and showing them in an `iframe` by setting the URLs to the `iframe`'s `src`. Imagine it's something like `example.com/pdf1.pdf`, `exmaple.com/pdf2.pdf`, etc.

Some of the URLS correctly respond with `Content-Type: application/pdf`.

However, a few of the responses have this instead: `Content-Type: application/octet-stream`.

This causes the PDF to be downloaded automatically by the browser, rather than be shown in the `iframe`.

I do not control the API.

I would strongly prefer jnot to build a proxy server.

Is there any client-side / Javascript solution to making the PDF render in the `iframe` even with `application/octet-stream` as the content type?

Some extensions can override the headers, but this site needs to work for other users and I can't expect them to all install the extensions.

Comment: are you able to get the data in the browser using AJAX (i.e. XMLHttpRequest or fetch)?

Comment: It's actually an s3 bucket on AWS. (I am getting authenticated URLs for S3 back from the API then iframing those urls). So I guess it could be a configuration issue, but unfortunately not one I can fix. As far as I can tell there are no useful parameters to add to change the content type.

Comment: I think it would be possible to read the data in the browser. I guess the proposal is then to load it directly into some custom viewer? I may end up doing that, though unfortunately a complication I didn't mention is that sometimes these can also be docx files so it would be a little tricky to support both formats.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have a JS solution to change the content type of the offending PDFs, I will offer you a reasonably acceptable alternative solution.

Google Docs, offer a online PDF viewer which can be hot-linked with the desired pdf-url which you can then embed into an iframe!

Like this...

```
var Url='https://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf'; // the pdf you want to load (NB: this one has the right MIME type though)    

var Gdocs='https://docs.google.com/gview?url='+Url+'&embedded=true'; // Google Docs url and way of passing the pdf to view
```

Now all you need is a fast way to get the content type of a pdf in order to decide which url to feed into your iframe...

```
fetch(Url).then(response=>{ 

 let CT=response.headers.get('Content-Type');

 if(CT=='application/pdf'){I.src=Url;} else {I.src=Gdocs;} 

}).catch(error=>{alert(error);});
```

Either way the PDF will end up displaying in your iframe!

Test HTML used...

```
<iframe id="I" src="" width="640" height="480" frameborder="1"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Their are a couple of JS librairies that render PDFs in the browser.

- https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/
- https://viewerjs.org/

These can also be combined with the iframe-resizer library to have the iframe match the size of the document if that is useful to you.